# metafont mode dpdfezzz

Tags: fonts, metafont

I'd like to look at the pk files metafont generates, in particular at their maximum resolution i.e. 8000dpi. I know that this is possible performing `mf \mode=dpdfezzz; mode_setup; \input filename.mf`; however, this does not work anymore (I'm using texlive on the latest version of Ubutnu, if necessary to be known), even if in modes.mf the driver `dpdfezzz` appears. How can I solve this problem hence be able to obtain the gf and pk files at the highest resolution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you quote the `\`  on the commandline?

this works for me from bash and texlive 2021

```
mf '\mode=dpdfezzz; mode_setup; \input cmr10.mf'
```

the terminal shows

```
$ mf '\mode=dpdfezzz; mode_setup; \input cmr10.mf'
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded base=mf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/cmr10.mf
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/cmbase.mf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/roman.mf
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romanu.mf
The letter A [65]
The letter B [66]
The letter C [67]
The letter D [68]
The letter E [69]
The letter F [70]
The letter G [71]
```

...
...
...

```
Breve accent [21]
Macron (bar) accent [22]
Scandinavian circle accent [23]
Cedilla accent [24]
Cross for Polish l and L [32]
Circumflex (hat) accent [94]
Dot accent [95]
Long Hungarian umlaut accent [125]
Tilde (squiggle) accent [126]
Umlaut (double dot) accent [127])
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/romlig.mf
The ligature ff [11]
The ligature fi [12]
The ligature fl [13]
The ligature ffi [14]
The ligature ffl [15])
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/cm/comlig.mf
Closing quotes [34]
Hyphen [45]
Opening quotes [92]
En dash [123]
Em dash [124]) ) )
Font metrics written on cmr10.tfm.
Output written on cmr10.8000gf (128 characters, 521748 bytes).
Transcript written on cmr10.log.
```